# Styling bootstrap carousel indicators into dots

Tags: html, css, carousel

Bit of a bootstrap noob here, I'm trying to style the carousel indicators in bootstrap to be dots instead of the default rectangles they give you. I have the carousel working and I'm trying to change the indicators through css by accessing as so:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;

}
```

The output does create circles, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3VCu.jpg), but the circles are too large, so I try changing the code to be:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;

}
```

and instead of the circles getting smaller, (at least I'm assuming that's what is supposed to happen..) they end up looking more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B92in.jpg).  I can't seem to find a way to work around this.  Does any body know how to fix this with CSS or another way around to having dots for the indicators instead of rectangles?  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Edit label element like this;

```
nav.carousel label {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -999px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 0 #999;
}
```

Hide radio button;

```
nav.carousel input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

 nav.carousel:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
nav.carousel label:hover {
  background: #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 0 #777;
}
nav.carousel input:checked + label {
  background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #bc1414);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
```

And use like this;

```
<nav class="carousel">
  <input id="item1" type="radio" name="dot" checked>
  <label for="item1">item 1</label>

  <input id="item2" type="radio" name="dot">
  <label for="item2">item 2</label>
</nav>
```

You can change width and hight as you wish. You can check working example;

https://jsfiddle.net/rnz9w1zz/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=rnz9w1zz